# Using EntityManager in a custom UserProvider

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am attempting to use Doctrines Entity Manager in a custom user provider in Symfony2.

As you can see, I pass it as an argument:

```
SnapsavedUserProvider: 
    class: Snap\ModelBundle\Security\SnapsavedUserProvider
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

And in the class I do:

```
namespace Snap\ModelBundle\Security;

use Snap\RestBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;

class SnapsavedUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface {

    protected $em;

    public function __construct($em) {
        $this->setEm($em);
        /* IF i var dump $this-getEm() here, i get the EntityManager */
    }

    public function getEm() {
        return $this->em;
    }

    public function setEm($em) {
        $this->em = $em;
    }


    public function loadUserByUsername($username) {

        var_dump($this->getEm());
        /* But its NULL here? */
        die();

        $user = $this->getEm()
                ->getRepository('SnapRestBundle:User')
                ->findOneBy(array('username' => $username));

        if ($user) {
            return $user;
        }

        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('Username "%s" does not exist.', $username));
    }
}
```

How come my EntityManager is NULL in the loadUserByUsername method? I mean, even if a new instance is used, the em is injected and set, is it not?

Comment: For the em to be injected you need to use the container.  $container->get('SnapsavedUserProvider');  Simply new'ing the object won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Why the getter and setter when you are injecting through the constructor? Plus you are missing a couple of methods required by the interface.

```
<?php

namespace Snap\ModelBundle\Security;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Snap\RestBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;

class SnapsavedUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{

    protected $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {

        $user = $this->em
            ->getRepository('SnapRestBundle:User')
            ->findOneBy(array('username' => $username));

        if ($user) {
            return $user;
        }

        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('Username "%s" does not exist.', $username));
    }

    /**
     * Refreshes the user for the account interface.
     *
     * It is up to the implementation to decide if the user data should be
     * totally reloaded (e.g. from the database), or if the UserInterface
     * object can just be merged into some internal array of users / identity
     * map.
     * @param UserInterface $user
     *
     * @return UserInterface
     *
     * @throws UnsupportedUserException if the account is not supported
     */
    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        // TODO: Implement refreshUser() method.
    }

    /**
     * Whether this provider supports the given user class
     *
     * @param string $class
     *
     * @return Boolean
     */
    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        // TODO: Implement supportsClass() method.
    }

}
```

Comment: I had the methods added, did not show them, anyway, its still NULL